# What are new features in linq in c#4.0?

Tags: c#, linq

I am C# developer , i like to use linq very much. i like to know new features of linq in c#4.0.i already know ZIP method there.Is there Any new methods like That?

Comment: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/10/28/linq-farm-covariance-and-contravariance-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/10/28/linq-farm-covariance-and-contravariance-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) Refer this link...

Answer (score 3):

There is the new `Zip()` extension method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx , the new `EF 4.0` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723 
While it isn't directly LINQ, they created the `Tuple` class tree http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx , and expanded `Action<T1, T2...>` and `Func<T1, T2...>` up to 10 parameters. I'm not sure if covariance and contravariance should be listed here (`IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, and "he" is one of the basic "objects" of LINQ)

Answer (score 0):

A number of these changes here are related to LINQ:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6y04yf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

PLINQ (Parallel LINQ) is an interesting addition in 4.0: start reading at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx